# Opening a CSV file in Python, with error handling

Tags: python, error-handling, csv

Trying to improve my function, as will be used by most of my code. I'm handling most common exception (IOError) and handling when data has no values.

```
READ_MODE = 'r'


def _ReadCsv(filename):
  """Read CSV file from remote path.

  Args:
    filename(str): filename to read.
  Returns:
    The contents of CSV file.
  Raises:
    ValueError: Unable to read file
  """
  try:
    with open(filename, READ_MODE) as input_file:
      data = input_file.read()
      if not data:
        raise ValueError('No data available')
  except IOError as e:
    logging.exception(e)
  return data
```

Comment: It's incorrect to to say you were "Unable to read file" when you successfully read an empty file.

Comment: Why not use Python's own csv module: https://devdocs.io/python~2.7/library/csv

Comment: Corrected message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only purpose of using a try/except that does not re-raise would be if it doesn't matter if there's an IOError. However, in this case, if an IOError occurs, it will be logged, then ignored and then return is going to raise a NameError - that 'data' is not defined. Since you are raising an error on empty results, I assume you handle that in the caller or want it to stop the process. In either case, I'd do something like

```
import logging
READ_MODE = 'r'


def _ReadCsv(filename):
    """Read CSV file from remote path.

    Args:
      filename(str): filename to read.
    Returns:
      The contents of CSV file.
    Raises:
      ValueError: Unable to read file
    """
    data = None
    try:
        with open(filename) as fobj:
            data = fobj.read()
    except IOError:
        logging.exception('')
    if not data:
        raise ValueError('No data available')
    return data
```

<s>Also, there's no need for the with open construct if you are just reading it. With open is preferred if you do more than one thing with the file object, so it gets closed properly. By not assigning the file open to a variable, it will get closed properly and garbage collected.</s>  Keep the with open, since garbage collection is an implementation detail you should not rely on any particular behavior.

With logging.exception, all the neat stuff that you see people doing manually is already taken care of. By simply calling it with an empty string, you get the full traceback, exception type and text without doing anything else.

```
logging.exception('')
```

Is equivalent to

```
logging.error(''.join(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info)))
```

or

```
logging.error('', exc_info=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't handle the exception in this part of the code, since it will hide errors. Just let it bubble up.

Comment: what if you want to handle them to provide more user friendly errors ?

Comment: In that case, handling the exception in _this_ part of the code would still be wrong. The job of this code snippet is to report any errors back to the caller. The caller can then decide how to handle any exceptions, be they `IOError` or anything else. The code from the original post hides the actual error from the caller since it just returns `None` in case of an error.

Comment: that is your point of view, because in the original question it does not say that, he wants to handle errors, not necessarily report them in a return. the errors could be logged to a file and later used to display them to the user.

Comment: That's not only my point of view, that is common practice and straight-forward error handling. Instead, what you suggest, first logging into a file and then reading the log data back to reconstruct a user-targeting error message from that is so unusual that it almost qualifies as obfuscation.

Comment: I know is a common patter, that is not my point, the fact of being common it does not means that is what the OP wanted specially since he/she did not mentioned that behavior